# Unix - extract files with certain number of lines

Tags: linux, unix, count, wc

(as an example), I have 10 files, named as such; file_name1.txt, file_name2.txt, file_name3.txt etc.

Each file has between 1-10 lines in it.

I want a command that will only print the files with a certain number of lines. i.e. I want to say **print the file names if that file has 1 line**, and then **print the file names with 2 lines** etc.

So I know to count the number of lines in the file it's `wc -l filename`, what's the next part, to say `if wc -l filename == 1, print filename`?

Answer (score 3):

I would use

```
wc -l * | awk '$1 == 10 {print $2}'
```

The `awk` invocation simply prints column 2 of every line where column 1 contains the value 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
export wanted_lines=10
for i in file*; do [[ `wc -l $i | nawk '{print $1}'` == $wanted_lines ]] && cat $i; done
```

**Update**

```
export wanted_lines=10
```

declare wanted_lines as a variable, initialize to 10, and mark for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands

```
for i in file*; do
```

This uses file globbbing to construct a list of every file in the current directory with a name that begins with "file".
Each iteration the i variable will refer to the next value in the list

```
[[ expression ]]
```

square braces - Evaluate the expression and return a 0 or 1

```
`command`
```

backticks - executes command and replaces with output of command

```
wc -l $i
```

count the lines of variable i, in this case a file name

```
| nawk '{print $1}'
```

stdout of previous command is fed to stdin of nawk, printing the first column, in this case a file name

```
== $wanted_lines
```

Equality test, will return true or false (0 or 1) respectively

```
&& expression
```

control operator will run expression if and only if the previous expression returns true

***In English: For every file beginning with the name "file", count the lines. If and only if the number of lines equals variable $wanted_lines, print the file.***

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy
- http://www.lemis.com/grog/Documentation/Lions/index.php
- http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.